# Calculate the sum of a specific array data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

After calling all the data from my database, I would like to try and calculate the individual values of my array. I have made 2 users state as "banned"

```
//get all banned status for all users
res.data.data.forEach((dataItem, index) => {
console.log(`Banned ${index}`, dataItem.banned);
```

[image]

I would like to try and get the sum of "banned" and "not banned" which in this case is "banned 2"  and "NotBanned 2"

tried this but dint work

```
  for (const dataItem of res.data.data) {
  
  let NotBanned = 0;   
  if(dataItem.banned === false){ 
  NotBanned++;
  console.log("Not Banned", NotBanned);
  }
 }

 for (const dataItem of res.data.data) {

   var BannedUsers = 0;
   if(dataItem.banned === true){ 
   BannedUsers++;
   console.log("Not Banned",BannedUsers);
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Try `const bannedCount = res.data.data.filter(({ banned }) => banned).length;`

Comment: What means "It did not work"? Please give more deatils on whoch result you get.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let 
  bannedUsers = 0,
  unBannedUsers = 0;

const response = res.data.data
for(let users = 0; users < response.length; users ++ ) {
   if(!response.banned) {
    unBannedUsers += users;
}
else {
   bannedUsers += users;
  }
}

console.log(`Banned Users : ${bannedUsers} , UnBanned Users : ${unBannedUsers}` )
```